# Android : Enable zoom in image popup

Tags: android

I am displaying images as a popup

```
public class LargeImagePopup extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final ImageView large;
    public LargeImagePopup(Context context,Bitmap image) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_largeimagepopup);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        Objects.requireNonNull(getWindow()).setLayout((w / 100) * 98, (h / 100) * 60);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setCancelable(true);
        large = findViewById(R.id.fullimageview);
        large.setImageBitmap(image);
        large.setOnClickListener(this);
        show();
    }
}
```

Can i enable zoom on image; if yes, how ?

Thank you